# Hibernate Envers audit Table Column Changes from jsonb to uuid

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a jsonb column in an Entity annotated as shown in the sample code. Everything works fine without the @Audited annotation. Adding the Audited annotation creates the org_master_aud table with the column custom_fields of type uuid instead of jsonb and the insert fails

```
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@Audited
public class OrgMaster {
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb",name="custom_fields",nullable=false)
    private JsonNode customFields;
}
```

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353)
.
.
.
.
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "{}"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2578)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2313)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:331)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:125)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 105 more
```

Find below the Snapshots of the custom_fields column in main and audit table where the audit table column is uuid whereas the main table is jsonb. Both are autogenerated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved after updating the hibernate version from 5.4.12.Final to 5.4.14.Final.

This was a bug introduced in versions > 5.4.10 and was fixed in 5.4.14. Here is the link to jira issue.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13886

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE which contains hibernate envers version 5.4.17.FINAL. Unfortunately, I am facing the exact same issue. Any idea perhaps?

Comment: Using `nativeQuery` and using positional parameter together with `@> '{}'::::jsonb` solved my issue. Just for somebody need a solution.